# iPad 1st generation, using as full screen browser (kiosk mode)

Tags: ipad, safari, fullscreen, web-browser

I have an old **1st generation iPad**, which **I want to recycle as a family photo/info display**. I plan to create a website with the required info and want to have the iPad to display just that site, refreshing periodically.

**Now, in it's safari browser, it always displays the top navigation bar.**

- Is there some kind of **full screen mode**, I am not aware of?
- Or is there a **3rd-Party app** (Kiosk app or something), that I can actually
  install and use on this old device today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a possibility of full screen mode by adding the web site to the Home Screen.

You do that by opening the web site in the Safari browser. Then click the "arrow out of the box" icon just to left of the address line. In the menu that pops up, click "Add to Home Screen".

Now'll you see an icon on the home screen for the web site. Click that and it should open up in full screen!

If it opens up, but still showing the bar at the top, you might need to add the following meta tag to your web site's code:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: It still shows the bar, when coming from the home screen, but I will modify my page later today, and see what happens.

Comment: This specific meta element seems to work. Like Magic!

Comment: Please note you need to remove and add again the page to the homescreen to be able to get it to work.

Comment: You can hide the menu bar by using the zoom feature: Settings > Accessibility > Zoom, then set zoom level appropriately (you'll of course lose several pixels on one or both sides depending on where you move the zoom area).